# Summarize browsing records in specific URL for specific user into one record regarding date in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I'm facing a problem in my report. The report calculates how many times a specific (company's applications) url's were viewed/opened ignoring user data.

What I need is for the query to count the times viewed regarding that every user might have not only opened the application but also browse in it (i.e. filter something, but it is still the same application), then the data shows that the same user in minutes or seconds difference opened the same application - every click/filtering/recompiling the page etc. makes a new entry record, which is misleading, because the report shows how many times the application was opened as an individual record. The applications (which are the same in every country) are used in different countries therefore the log data is in different servers.

There are 4 tables from different servers, which have log entry data of the applications (url's), and they have to be inserted into one with already summarizes log entry data.

A small piece of the one table with the data:

[image]

A small piece of the second table just to see that the only difference between tables is `litintranet`, `wokintranet`:

[image]

There you can see that for the LogApp IFP the same user browsed with difference of seconds. But it should have only one record (just for opening the app), but has 3 records because the user probably filtered something or refreshed the page etc.

I need a query that summarizes this information and enters the new summarized / reduced records into a new table. The new table will be used for reports as the correct data of records.

The output should look like this:
[image]

How can the summarizing be done?

Thank you for your help

Comment: from your tables.. what would your desired results look like?

Comment: can you make it easier for us to answer by including the actual info in text rather than images? output is ok.. but change the input to be selectable text please